# How to add new item like "Create New" to the dropdown in Jquery Autocomplete when typed string does not match

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

If the item does not match, I want "Create New" appear as an item in the dropdown, or "Create New" can appear everytime when user starts typing. Either way would work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code or more details, you best bet is to just add some code to append the "Create New" item to the dropdown. Probably after the post/fetch code that triggers on users typing.

If you post code we can help more by modifying it. The above responses are kinda vague and generally more advice due to the lack of description/code. Do I need to say again more description and code? :)